# What does the WMR key under Windows Error Reporting do?

Tags: windows-error-reporting

I've been working with Windows Error Reporting (specifically Corporate Error Reporting with AEM and an SCOM server). I'm in the process of some debugging. I've been combing through the registry for WER settings -- which I've found in several places -- and I've found some information on the settings and exactly what they do from MS (most of it from Dr. Watson days). My question is just trying to understand one of the less documented keys.

What is the:
`(HKLM/HKCU)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\WMR`
key used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be used for [stop sending error messages to Microsoft](https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/how-do-i-stop-sending-error-messages-to-microsoft/32329).

> It appears that the only option available to Home users in Windows 10 is to disable Error Reporting via modifying the Disabled key in the registry.
>
> Open Regedit. Navigate to:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\WMR
> ```
>
> Find the key "Disabled". The default value of this key is 0. Double click it to edit, change the value to 1 and save."

Nevertheless, I wasn't yet able to find an official source (from MSDN or a similar) to support this.